# Proof of Cochran's theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistical-inference

I'm trying to understand a proof of Cochran's theorem

> Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be a random sample from an $N(0,1)$
>   distribution and let $x$ represent the vector of these observations.
>   Suppose $$x^\top x = \sum_{i=1}^k x^\top Q_i x$$ where $Q_i$ is PSD
>   with rank $r_i$. The $k$ quadratic forms in the sum are independent
>   and $x^\top Q_i x\sim \chi^2(r_i), \, i=1,2,\ldots,k$ if and only if
>   $\sum_{i=1}^k r_i=n$.

In the first few lines, the proof I'm reading says if $\sum_{i=1}^k r_i = n$, then $I= \sum_{i=1}^k Q_i$. I don't see why this is at all true nor can I prove it. Can someone provide some intuition/explanation for this?

Comment: Is there a tacit universal quantifier here, saying that the displayed equality holds for all values of $x\in\mathbb R^{n\times1} \text{ ?} \qquad$

Comment: I believe so. I just don't see why the ranks need to sum up to $n$ in order to say $\sum_{i=1}^k Q_i = I$.

Comment: Where did you read this? I am a bit suspicious of the statement of the theorem.

Comment: Matrix Algebra for Linear Models by Marvin Gruber.

Comment: I think the sum of the ranks can't be less than n for right off the bat, as it would no longer be possible for $x^Tx = \sum_{i=1}^k x^T Q_i x$ to hold. So are you asking why we can't have the sum be greater than n?

Comment: Also, does it help if we rewrite the assumption as $$ x^t \left(I - \sum_{i=1}^k Q_i \right) x = 0?$$

Comment: Why does the sum of the ranks being less than $n$ imply $x^T x \neq \sum_{i=1}^k x^T Q_i x$? That's what I'm wondering.

Comment: Because $rank (\sum_{i=1}^k Q_i) \leq \sum_{i=1}^k rank(Q_i)$.

Comment: It looks to me as if the language in which Gruber states the theorem is confused and vague.

https://books.google.com/books?id=Ox9YAgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Matrix+Algebra+for+Linear+Models+by+Marvin+Gruber&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW-5Kp5M7bAhWJ6YMKHZqHDBEQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=cochran's%20theorem&f=false

Comment: @Glassjawed : Could you write $\operatorname{rank}(A)$ instead of $rank(A)$? This not only de-italicizes it, but also results in proper spacing in things like $\operatorname{rank} A.$ Notice the context-dependent nature of the spacing seen in the contrast between the spaces to the right of "rank" in $\operatorname{rank}(A)$ and $\operatorname{rank} A. \qquad$

Comment: Try this version of the statement of Cochran's theorem:

https://books.google.com/books?id=o5buBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141&dq=%22allan+gut%22+%22cochran%27s+theorem%22&source=bl&ots=lKO7v4lhKq&sig=YlIo8-0WB2yXjeAdA_ZrotgDd9o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnqdn05s7bAhWs5oMKHfyjBk8Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22allan%20gut%22%20%22cochran's%20theorem%22&f=false

Comment: Can you use the fact that $Q_i$ is decomposed as $Q_i = U \Lambda_i U^*$ for $U$ unitary and then use some form of unitary invariance?

Comment: In particular, if $\tilde{x} = U^{\ast} x$, then $\tilde{x}$ should still have normally distributed entries (with some scaling in the variance?)

Comment: @MichaelHardy yes I like that proof more. However, the inductive step there isn't quite clear because you can't use the same orthogonal matrix $C$ when extending to $k > 2$...

Comment: Okay I see I guess you could always look at splitting one of quadratic forms in two over and over again in order to carry out the inductive step and so you have a bunch of submatrices that are orthogonal w.r.t subspaces. I still think that's a nontrivial part of a proof to omit IMHO.